# Webpack proper way to import and bundle modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, zurb-foundation

I'm working with a Wordpress framework built on Foundation and uses Webpack to bundle the JS. Very new to Webpack.

When I add Slick.js to my project I use:

```
//import JS

import './lib/slick';

//init

$('.my-class').slick({});
```

This works as expected and I get no errors.

However, when I added sweetalert2.js like this:

```
import './lib/sweetalert2';

//init

swal({
  title: 'Error!',
  text: 'Do you want to continue',
  type: 'error',
  confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
});
```

I got swal is not defined errors.

However, this worked and I got no errors when initing.

```
import swal from './lib/sweetalert2';
```

I am guessing this has something to do with exposing the function. However, I am trying to understand why slick.js worked without doing so and sweetalert2 did not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like slick is a jQuery plugin, so loading the library just bolts it onto your global jQuery instance, but sweetalert2 is a standalone and doesn't want to just create a global object (because that's generally a Bad Idea).

Comment: Thanks. So, would be better practice to do something like import "import slick from './lib/slick';"  This worked as well for slick.js . I can't say I am loving Webpack so far. Before I would just use gulp and combine all my JS and everything worked.

Comment: I don't think you need to, because you don't need to use the `slick` object except through jQuery. I'm webpack convert and would never go back to gulp, but that's because it's so much easier to maintain a project if I know exactly which bits use which dependencies, rather than just assuming everything is a global.